# Resolution problem after exiting from a game (Wine)

Tags: resolution, wine, games

I am playing GTA San Andreas using Wine. When I quit the game, everything looks weird. How can I fix this?

Edit: After a restart, it solves this issue. But How can I fix without restart.

[image: Google Chrome]

[image: Files]

[image: Google Chrome]

Comment: What is wierd ?

Comment: Resolution. See the screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to fix this is:

- <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> - `switchboard`
- Open "Displays".
- Set your normal screen resolution.

I am not aware of any way to have this fix itself automatically.

Comment: Because of the resolution, I was not able see Apply Changes in "Displays", but after `3 Tabs + Return` it applied changes. Perfect Solution. Thank you :)

Comment: @TirthPatel in that case, you can use ALT and the left mouse button to drag the window.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with Wine. Because GTA SA uses some method to close itself which Wine is not familiar with, it exits unexpectedly. This makes Wine unable to reset the resolution back.

The most easy fix for this is to run GTA SA in a "virtual desktop". You can do this by going to *Wine configuration*, Graphics and turning on virtual desktops.

Comment: I tried to open GTA SA in Virtual Desktop but it closes virtual desktop and doesn't open the game.